# Is there a way to make my Python program run a lot faster?

Tags: python, performance

I have written a computer program in python but it runs a lot slower than I want it to.

Here is the code:

```
from gzip import GzipFile
from cStringIO import StringIO
import re
import webbrowser
import time
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import os
import sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import eventlet
from eventlet.green import urllib2
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib

TITLE_MATCH = re.compile(r'(.*) \(\d{1,10}.{1,100}\)$')
ADDRESS_MATCH = re.compile(r'.{1,100}\((.*), .{4,14}, United States\)$')
LOCATION_LISTING = re.compile(r'http://www\.locationary\.com/place/en/US/.{1,50}/.{1,50}/.{1,100}\.jsp')

def download(url):
    print "Downloading:", url
    s = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    if s[:2] == '\x1f\x8b': # assume it's gzipped data
        ifh = GzipFile(mode='rb', fileobj=StringIO(s))
        s = ifh.read()
    print "Downloaded: ", url
    return s

def replace_chars(text, replacements):
    return ''.join(replacements.get(x,x) for x in text)

def handle_listing(listing_url):
    listing_document = BeautifulSoup(download(listing_url))

    # ignore pages that link to yellowpages
    if not listing_document.find("a", href=re.compile(re.escape("http://www.yellowpages.com/") + ".*")):
        listing_title = listing_document.title.text
        reps = {' ':'-', ',':'', '\'':'', '[':'', ']':''}
        if TITLE_MATCH.match(listing_title) is not None:
            title, = TITLE_MATCH.match(listing_title).groups()
            address, = ADDRESS_MATCH.match(listing_title).groups()

            yellow_page_url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/%s/%s?order=distance" % (
                replace_chars(address, reps),
                replace_chars(title, reps),
            )

            yellow_page = BeautifulSoup(download(yellow_page_url))

            page_url = yellow_page.find("h3", {"class" : "business-name fn org"})
            if page_url:
                page_url = page_url.a["href"]

                business_name = title[:title.index(",")]

                page = BeautifulSoup(download(page_url))
                yellow_page_address =  page.find("span", {"class" : "street-address"})
                if yellow_page_address:

                    if SequenceMatcher(None, address, yellow_page_address.text).ratio() >= 0.5:
                        pid, = re.search(r'p(\d{5,20})\.jsp', listing_url).groups(0)
                        page_escaped = replace_chars(page_url, {':':'%3A', '/':'%2F', '?':'%3F', '=':'%3D'})

                        final_url = "http://www.locationary.com/access/proxy.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=proxy_jsp$JspView$SaveAction&inPlaceID=%s&xxx_c_1_f_987=%s" % (
                                pid, page_escaped)
                        return final_url

def log_in(final_url):
    data = urllib.urlencode({"inUserName":"jacob.grannis@gmail.com", "inUserPass":"secretword"})
    jar = cookielib.FileCookieJar("cookies")
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))
    opener.addheaders.append(('User-agent', 'Mozilla/4.0'))
    opener.addheaders.append(('Referer', 'http://www.locationary.com/'))
    opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie','site_version=REGULAR; __utma=47547066.912030359.1322003402.1324959960.1325009956.58; __utmz=47547066.1324655802.52.13.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=cache:dr23PN5fUj4J:www.locationary.com/%20locationary; nickname=jacob501; jforumUserId=1; PMS=1; locaCountry=1033; locaState=1786; locaCity=Vancouver; JSESSIONID=5CDDA2D527C20A6CDD04936115DE3FA2; PSESSIONID=c677beb4e6b8d58f1443d9b9585b225f579ef29a; Locacookie=enable; __utmb=47547066.1.10.1325009956; __utmc=47547066'))
    opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie','Cookie: site_version=REGULAR; __utma=47547066.912030359.1322003402.1324959960.1325009956.58; __utmz=47547066.1324655802.52.13.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=cache:dr23PN5fUj4J:www.locationary.com/%20locationary; nickname=jacob501; jforumUserId=1; PMS=1; locaCountry=1033; locaState=1786; locaCity=Vancouver; JSESSIONID=5CDDA2D527C20A6CDD04936115DE3FA2; PSESSIONID=c677beb4e6b8d58f1443d9b9585b225f579ef29a; Locacookie=enable; __utmb=47547066.4.10.1325009956; __utmc=47547066'))
    request = urllib2.Request("https://www.locationary.com/index.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=tile_loginBar_jsp$JspView$LoginAction", data)
    response = opener.open(request) 
    url = str(final_url)
    anything = opener.open(url)
    page = anything.read()

States = [#'Alabama',
          #'Alaska',
          'Arizona',
          'Arkansas',
          'California',
          'Colorado',
          'Connecticut',
          'Delaware',
          'Florida',
          'Georgia',
          'Hawaii',
          'Idaho',
          'Illinois',
          'Indiana',
          'Iowa',
          'Kansas',
          'Kentucky',
          'Louisiana',
          'Maine',
          'Maryland',
          'Massachusetts',
          'Michigan',
          'Minnesota',
          'Mississippi',
          'Missouri',
          'Montana',
          'Nebraska',
          'Nevada',
          'New_Hampshire',
          'New_Jersey',
          'New_Mexico',
          'New_York',
          'North_Carolina',
          'North_Dakota',
          'Ohio',
          'Oklahoma',
          'Oregon',
          'Pennsylvania',
          'Rhode_Island',
          'South_Carolina',
          'South_Dakota',
          'Tennessee',
          'Texas',
          'Utah',
          'Vermont',
          'Virginia',
          'Washington',
          'West_Virginia',
          'Wisconsin',
          'Wyoming']

Cities = []

def find_cities(state):
    state_url = 'http://www.locationary.com/place/en/US/' + str(state)
    state_document = download(str(state_url))
    findCities = re.compile('<b>(.*)</b>')
    getCities = re.findall(findCities,state_document)

    for City in getCities:
        reps = {' ':'_'}
        City = replace_chars(City, reps)
        Cities.append(str(City))

bestworst = ['0','1']

def main():
    for state in States:
        find_cities(state)
        for city in Cities:
            for num in range(0,1):
                for pagenum in range(15,16):
                    print '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
                    print '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
                    if str(num) == '0':
                        print str(state) + ', ' + str(city) + ', ' + 'Best Profiles' + ', ' + 'Page ' + str(pagenum)
                    else:
                        print str(state) + ', ' + str(city) + ', ' + 'Worst Profiles' + ', ' + 'Page ' + str(pagenum)
                    START_URL = 'http://www.locationary.com/place/en/US/' + str(state) + '/' + city + '-page' + str(pagenum) + '/?ACTION_TOKEN=NumericAction&order=' + str(num)
                    pool = eventlet.GreenPool()
                    listings_document = BeautifulSoup(download(START_URL))
                    listings = listings_document.findAll("a", href = LOCATION_LISTING)
                    listings = [listing['href'] for listing in listings]

                    count_listings = 0

                    for final_url in pool.imap(handle_listing, listings):
                        print final_url
                        if final_url is not None:
                            log_in(final_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is there a way to make it faster or is it impossible? It has to download URL's from the internet a lot but I'm pretty sure I can't make my internet connection 10 to 50 times faster than it already is...And my computer isn't very slow...so, is there any way to make my program, say, 10-50 times faster? I know that might sound ridiculous, but how do professional programmers make their programs faster then?

Comment: It belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can use several threads to fetch the different pages.

Comment: The way professional programmers make their programs faster is by profiling. Look at Python's cProfile module.

Answer (score 6):

The first step to speeding up any program is to understand why it's slow -- i.e., where is the time going? The tool programmers use to do this is called a *profiler*. Standard Python includes several of these: you can learn about them [here.](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html)

Once you've learned to use a profiler, run it on your program to identify the *hot spots*, or locations where the program spends the most time. Then try to speed the program up in one of two ways:

1. Try to make the hot spot take less time; or
2. Try to make it so that the hot spot is executed fewer times.

Usually #2 is more fruitful. Choosing a better or more appropriate algorithm can reduce the amount of code that is executed.

Don't waste time *guessing* why the program is slow; *measure* it, then invest your energy in fixing the real problem. Programmers are notoriously bad at guessing where performance problems lie.

Answer (score 2):

The way programmers optimize code is using profilers, python makes several available. [Here is a great article](http://onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2005/12/15/profiling.html)  to get you started.

You can call [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) from the command line:

```
python -m timeit myprogram.py
```

The link above has a bunch of examples of using timeit. Once you figure out where your bottlenecks lie, you can think about ways to fix them. If your program is spending an inordinate amount of time in the download() function, you can think about introducing some kind of concurrency and downloading things in the background, while your program continues to use BeautifulSoup to parse an extract info from things that have been downloaded.

The key here is to see:

1. Where your program is spending the most time.
2. Of the locations in step #1, where you can optimize the easiest

For a hypothetical example, if your regular expressions are particularly poorly written, they could be taking a long time, and you could then work to optimize. I saying "hypothetical" because in practice, your regular expressions are unlikely to be a significant bottleneck unless you are executing them millions of times or something weird like that.